# signing using RSA private key Windows cryptographic API

Tags: cryptography, rsa, microsoft-metro, signing

I am working on a metro app and working on signing an Oauth request for a Google application.
I am unable to Import my keypair properly into the JS code .
The same problem has been asked here but still unresolved-
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/d599ff36-75f2-4393-af10-60beb1842ece
I have my key in the format "---START PRIV KEY---MIC898 blah blah ----END PRIV KEY--".

When I try to import it into my code using ImportKeyPair function, I get an exception that

> "there was a problem at time of encoding or decoding".

I am getting my key using openSSL "rsagen" tool which I believe gives a pair of Private and Public key.

Comment: Try to use more common tags gaurav, maybe read the FAQ of this site so you can use it more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your PEM formatted RSA keys to DER first using `openssl rsa <arguments>`.

Comment: PS the private key also contains the public exponent, so you should be able to extract both from the structure

Comment: thanks. The problem was that the pvt key was in base64 format so I encoded it and worked .I think this has the same effect as what you suggested.

Comment: PEM format is ASN.1 DER encoded using base 64 but with the `---THIS IS A HEADER STUFF---` and `---THIS IS THE END OF THE STUFF---` added to it to identify the object within (and to separate objects so you can chain them).